# SQL-EX.ru query problemset #28

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write an SQL query to solve a question at www.sql-ex.ru (Q. 28), I got the correct result, but I got this error "Your query failed on third checking database."

**SQL Query Question:**

> To within two decimal digits, define the average quantity of paint per square.

**SQL Notes:**

> Database schema consists of 3 tables:
>
> utQ (Q_ID int, Q_NAME varchar(35)), utV (V_ID int, V_NAME varchar(35), V_COLOR char(1)),
>
> utB (B_Q_ID int, B_V_ID int, B_VOL tinyint, B_DATETIME datetime).
>   The table utQ includes square identifier, square name. Note that non-painted square is black.
>
> utV includes balloon identifier, balloon name, and paint color.
>   The table utB shows information on painting square with paint balloon and includes the square identifier, the balloon identifier, the paint quantity, and time of painting.
>
> - It should be noted that balloon may be of one from three colors: red (V_COLOR='R'), green (V_COLOR='G'), or blue (V_COLOR='B');
> - any balloon is originally full with volume of 255;
> - square color is defined in accordance with RGB rule, i.e. R=0, G=0, B=0 is black, whereas R=255, G=255, B=255 is white;
> - any record in the table utB decreases paint quantity in the balloon by B_VOL and increase paint quantity in the square by the same value;
> - B_VOL must be more than 0 and less or equal 255;
> - paint quantity of the same color in one square may not be over 255;
> - paint quantity in a balloon may not be less than 0;
> - time of painting (B_DATETIME) is given to within a second, i.e. it does not contain milliseconds.

**Scheme**

[image: Scheme]

**My Code**

```
WITH x AS (SELECT b_q_id, b_v_id, ball.v_color, b_vol as vol FROM utb
JOIN utv ball
ON utb.b_v_id = ball.v_id)
, y AS (
SELECT b_q_id, v_color, totalcolor = CASE WHEN SUM(vol) > 255 THEN 255
ELSE SUM(vol) END FROM x
GROUP BY b_q_id, v_color),
z AS(
SELECT b_v_id, totalbcolor = 
CASE WHEN SUM(b_vol) > 255 THEN 255
ELSE SUM(b_vol)
END
FROM utb
GROUP BY b_v_id)
, a AS
(SELECT b_q_id, SUM(totalcolor) totalacolor FROM y GROUP BY b_q_id)
, b AS 
(SELECT b_q_id,b_v_id, totalacolor FROM a, z)
, c AS
(SELECT DISTINCT b.b_q_id, totalacolor FROM b
INNER JOIN utb
ON (b.b_q_id = utb.b_q_id AND b.b_v_id = utb.b_v_id))

SELECT 
CAST(CAST(SUM(totalacolor) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) 
/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utq)AS NUMERIC(8,2))  
 FROM c
```

**Correct Answer**

> 386.25

**Comments**
My code is probably overly long.  But, there is probably a shorter way of doing it.  But, I still don't get where I'm wrong.  Please help.

Answer (score 5):

here your code)

```
SELECT  CONVERT(NUMERIC(15,2),SUM(COALESCE(UB.B_VOL,0)) / CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.Q_ID)))
FROM    utQ AS UQ
        LEFT JOIN utB AS UB ON UQ.Q_ID = UB.B_Q_ID
        LEFT JOIN utV AS UV ON UB.B_V_ID = UV.V_ID
```

test below

[image]

Comment: There's no need to LEFT JOIN utV table.

Comment: You should test your assumptions before posting the comment

Comment: @Vasily - your code works, though can you explain why you need the coalesce command? Without it I get "Your query failed on third checking database" which is what I got to by my own. I don't understand what's my problem and why I need to use coalesce.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli `COALESCE` function is required for removing of `null` (similar with `NULLIF` and `ISNULL`, but I use it because of habit and also it have some advantages with respect to other `null` transformation functions) in case when `UQ.Q_ID` and `UB.B_Q_ID` will not matched. So, if these two matching  keys will not matched then `COALESCE` will return `0`, and for next calculation it will means that average quantity of paint per square will equal to `0` (because data about "amount of paint being applied" to some squares is absent in table `utB`).

Comment: @DavidRefaeli  `sql-ex` is very interesting resource not only because you've get opportunity to obtain knowledge about how to write a queries on `tsql`, but also you will receive a chance to get experience on how work with data in "blind" mode, means that you type the queries with have no idea about data availability and consistency (if you think that your code is perfect, but it's not return correct results on some of the servers, then you should apply "what if" and change your code to get desired results)

Comment: @Vasily - thanks. Could you maybe also help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101657/sql-ex-ru-select-statement-exercise-51

Answer (score 0):

if you want go alongside help topics you could use this query:

```
SELECT cast(SUM(case when UB.B_VOL IS NULL then 0 else UB.B_VOL end) /cast(COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.Q_ID) as float) as decimal(8,2))FROM utQ AS UQ
    LEFT JOIN utB AS UB ON UQ.Q_ID = UB.B_Q_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(15,2),
(
SELECT SUM(total_paint) * 1.0 / COUNT(Q_ID) AS avg_paint 
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT utQ.Q_ID, 
CASE
WHEN SUM(B_VOL) IS NULL
THEN 0
ELSE SUM(B_VOL)
END
AS total_paint
FROM utQ
LEFT JOIN utB ON utB.B_Q_ID = utQ.Q_ID
GROUP BY utQ.Q_ID
) AS tmp
)
)
```